# Creating a Whatsapp like model in Rails Framework.

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Background**: I am new to Rails and I have gone through Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial.
I have read Agile Web Development with Rails 5.
So for practice I was trying to design WhatsApp like framework and got stuck while creating User and Group model.

**Problem**: I have tried different user and group model relationship and each one is failing for some reason.I have tried few paths so I will enlist them below.*I don't need code, just a correct database relationship between User,Admin,Group,Participants*.Also we should be able to add relationship through UI.

1. We have two tables User and Group.Admin belongs_to Group.Group has_many Admins. Group has_many partcipants. Participant belongs_to group.Participant is a new table having user_id and group_id.
2. We have three tables User,Group and Admin_Participant.Admin_Participant table contains admin_of column and participant_of column and one user_id column.admin_of and participant_of will contain group_ids.
3. Similar to first but we have a different table for admin which contains user_id , group_id, boolean table for is_admin.
4. Group is reference to User and admin column is boolean.Participant is added to User table and is also a boolean.

**One more Thing** As soon as a user creates group he is assigned to be admin of that group.Remember the restrictions of participants.

Comment: It should be possible with just three tables: groups, users and participations(user_id, group_id, is_admin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 tables ( and their models ) should suffice.

1. User

   - has many participants
   - has many groups through participants
2. Group

   - attribute: created_by ( user id )
   - has many participants
   - has many users through participant
3. Participant

   - belongs to group
   - belongs to user
   - attribute admin

The above should work *provided* that an admin is also a participant.
If there are admins who are not participants, then a extra column for 'participating', or 'non-participant' is required.

There is no need for an admin table unless the admin has other attributes.

In case you haven't, it's good to go through the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Good Implementation. Its much easier to add restrictions regarding admin using another table of participants with a column of admin.Size of user model is also reduced , clearing the space for attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So this might be too far down the rabbit hole but I see only 2 tables, User and Groups. A user can be a admin and/or participant. The relationship between user and group would probably be has_or_belongs_to_many as a user can belong to many groups and a group can have many users. Further, to accomplish the user/admin/participant distinction, I might even subclass it with STI(single table inheritance) instead of using booleans to determine if someone is an admin or not.

Comment: but to power a habtm relationship, you need a third table.

Comment: That's true, I should have said 2 models.

Answer (score 0):

as you specified you need a relationship model not code.
i think i can help.
you might have to reshape your whole database, but if i were you, i would do it like ...

1. User - name , user_id , mob_no , groups (before someone need to log in , my app would send em the code through which they can verify that they are the owner of that mob no. //we would not discuss that in detail/// )

########   has_many: groups

2. group - name , users , admin(boolean) (i made a different column for admin, the users column stores the user_id of the user , when someone creates a group he automatically becomes the admin , so admin column becomes true for that user id.. and later that admin can make other  admin as well...[if you have problem implementing this i would suggest opening up michael hartl's book and read how he made an example user an admin and that admin could delete other users , that will help])

########## belongs_to: user

3. i do not  understand how you would implement the admin of a group to add users to group,
   so in this case i would like to suggest the following -
      $ if the user has followed another user he can add that user to the group...
      $ or a facebook like system " where user gets users invite to the group ,and later its upon him to decide whether he want to join or not.

% pls comment and lemme know if this helps. and any other suggestion.

Comment: Please take the time to use proper formatting, punctuation, capitalization and grammar. Stack Overflow is an online reference book, and those things do matter.